# I don't get the correct output even thouh my code has no errors

Tags: c++, function, loops, recursion, math

I tried to create a program that calculates the combination and i am using codeblocks i don't think there's a problem with my code i downloaded gdb32 for Mingw from the internet as my tutor used it and it was not included by default. I tried several test cases and different methods that include recursion and iterations there are no errors earlier i used to get id **returned 1 exit status** error but now there are no errors but the output is incorrect

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int factorial (int n)
{
    int i=1,fact;
    if(n==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while(n!=0)
        {
            fact=i*n;
            n--;
        }
    }
    return fact;
}
int nCr(int n, int r)//Iterartive combinatrics
{
    int num,den;
    num=factorial(n);
    den=factorial(r)*factorial(n-r);
    return num/den;
}
int NCR (int n, int r)//recursive combinatrics
{
    if (n==r||n==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return NCR(n-1,r-1)+NCR(n-1,r);
    }
}
int main()
{
    cout << nCr(5,2)<< endl;
    cout << nCr(5,1)<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger to find your bug.

Comment: Obviously your code does have errors. Do teachers not talk about the different kinds of errors?

Comment: `return num/den;` remember integer math truncates any floating point so if num and den are both positive and num < den then the returned value is 0.

Comment: The function names `nCr` and `NCR` would be fine if there was just one. Otherwise we have a nightmare.

Comment: "I don't get the correct output even thouh my code has no errors" - No compiler errors is *not* the same as your program having no errors. Not even close.

Comment: Looks like `factorial` always returns `1`.

Comment: If you don't get the correct output, then by definition your program has errors.  You need to expand your understanding of what "error" means.

Comment: @OP -- Just to make it simple -- if you were asked to write a program to add two numbers, but instead the program subtracted the two numbers, the code will compile with no errors, however the program did not do the proper task. That's basically what others are referring to when they say that having no compiler errors  and not having logical errors are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
while(n!=0)
{
    fact=i*n;
    n--;
}
```

You want:

```
while(n!=1)
{
    fact*=n;
    n--;
}
```

`fact` should be initialized to 1.
Also, using `int` type is not the best option for computing numerical algorithms since it can not store much larger value (limited to ~2E9) and obviously can not return less than a unit value (so it'll be wrong for anything serious).

At least, even if not perfect, you should use `double` instead.
Ideally, you can even implement your own `Fraction` type to support true value and not approximations.

Also, you should try to avoid this kind of code:

```
int num,den;
num = ...
den = ...
```

Instead prefer this:

```
int num = ...;
int den = ...;
```

Later, you'll find that `auto` is easier so you'll be able to write this:

```
auto num = ...;
auto den = ...;
```

A compiler assert the syntax of your code is correct, it can not assert the intention of the code (only you can). So if the algorithm you've written is wrong, but with a correct syntax, you'll get a wrong output. Therefore, you must first think about the algorithm before going in the compile & rework cycle.

For example, in your exercice, I'd have checked the `factorial` output first (since the combinatorial is trivial) and spotted that the algorithm you've written is wrong. Make small steps, tests and grow the system and loop, it's much easier than trying to debug a complex system at once.

Good luck!